# ExpressJS: Retrieving images from MongoDB and displaying them in Jade

Tags: image, node.js, mongodb, pug, express

I am looking for good ways to retrieve images from MongoDB and display them. For example, to retrieve a profile picture and display it on a profile page, this is how I am currently doing it:

**profile page**

```
block content
  h1= session.user.name
  img(src='/avatars')
```

**routes**

```
exports.avatars = (req, res) ->
  users.find req.session.user, (err, user) ->
    if user
      res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type': 'image/png'})
      res.end(user.avatar.data, 'binary')
    else
      res.locals.flash = err
      res.render('index', {title: 'Home'})
```

Basically I render the profile page, and the `img` tag sends a request back to the server to pick up the picture of the user from the database. Im saving the images as BinData in MongoDB. Not using `GridFS` because I expect the pictures to be small.

Is there a better way to do this?? I tried to send the image data directly to the jade view using `res.render('users/show', {picture: data})` but the `img` tag didn't like that and I'm not clear on why. Is this approach a dead end?

Any comments/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the image data directly to jade view would work if

**a)** you base64 encoded the image data

**b)** prefixed with "data:"

But I would not recommend you do this way, you essentially in-lining the image in your html.

You should instead create a separate route to handle your images/avatars.

For example the image source for your avatars should be something like

```
img(src='http://mydomain.com/avatars/user1.jpg')
```

When the browser requests this image you then respond with image data retrieved from mongo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what you are saying for one picture, but what if I needed to display a whole array of pictures and text. How would i get all of this information to my view?

Comment: Well, then you will have loads of img tags along side any text you need to display. Each of these tag will then request the appropiate image from the images/avatars route.

Comment: But at the time the page is rendered, I don't know how many images there will be. For example, maybe a user has many pictures of his friends stored in the DB, and I want to display these pictures on his profile page...

Comment: You will first need to query the db to work out how many images a given use has. As result of this you generate the appropiate number of image tags. Finally the browser will request this images and they will be displayed on the page.

Comment: I think you are confusing the images/BinData with the initial markup you need to display the images. This explains why you mentioned "display images with jade" in the title.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I understand views can be dynamic; i just didn't understand the process of transferring information between the view and server that make it so.   You have definitely earned the accepted answer here but if you don't mind, let me ask one last question.   These images that I want to display: What if they are the result of a server-side call to an external API, say Amazon.com? Thus I cannot know how many images I will get back, but I still want to display all of them..?

Comment: Typically you would get a json response from an external api. First you parse the json so that it becomes a normal javascript object. Then you would use the foreach method to loop over the results to determine how many images it contains etc.